# Delete row of DT data table in Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have a shiny app that displays data frame data in a DT table. In the app I have a button that I when clicked will delete the selected rows. It works the first time I select rows and click the delete button but after clicking again the wrong rows are deleted and any previously deleted rows reappear. I'm assuming this is because it reloads the data frame (from a csv) when I call `DT::renderDataTable()`.

How can I re render the table after deleting a selected row from the the data frame?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This could get you started:

ui.R

```
    library(shiny)
    library(DT)
    shinyUI(fluidPage(
       titlePanel("Delete rows with DT"),
              sidebarLayout(
                sidebarPanel(
                    actionButton("deleteRows", "Delete Rows")
                ),
                mainPanel(
                   dataTableOutput("table1")
                )
              )
    ))
```

server.R

```
    library(shiny)
    library(DT)
    library(dplyr)
    df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = letters[1:10])

    shinyServer(function(input, output) {
            values <- reactiveValues(dfWorking = df)

           observeEvent(input$deleteRows,{

                    if (!is.null(input$table1_rows_selected)) {

                            values$dfWorking <- values$dfWorking[-as.numeric(input$table1_rows_selected),]
                    }
            })

            output$table1 <- renderDataTable({
                    values$dfWorking
            })

    })
```

Comment: I have problems to implement `df`, if it is a reactiveVal itself (coming from another shiny-module). Does anyone have a hint on this?